# Kotlin coroutines block main thread in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am new in Kotlin and coroutines. I have a `fun` in my activity and inside it, check `User` username and password and if its true, return `Users` object.
every thing is Ok. but when I press button, my activity blocked and wait for response of `Users` login.
I use this fun:

```
private fun checkLogin() : Boolean {           
        runBlocking {
            coroutineScope {
                launch {
                    user = viewModel.getUserAsync(login_username.text.toString(), login_password.text.toString()).await()
                }
            }
            if(user == null){
                return@runBlocking false
            }
            return@runBlocking true
        }
        return false
    }
```

It's my ViewModel :

```
class LoginViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    val context: Context = app.applicationContext
    private val userService = UsersService(context)

    fun getUserAsync(username: String, password: String) = GlobalScope.async {
        userService.checkLogin(username, password)
    }
}
```

UsersService:

```
class UsersService(ctx: Context) : IUsersService {
        private val db: Database = getDatabase(ctx)
        private val api = WebApiService.create()
        override fun insertUser(user: Users): Long {
            return db.usersDao().insertUser(user)
        }

        override suspend fun checkLogin(username: String, pass: String): Users? {
            return api.checkLogin(username, pass)
        }
    }

    interface IUsersService {
        fun insertUser(user: Users) : Long
        suspend fun checkLogin(username: String, pass: String): Users?
    }
```

And it is my apiInterface:

```
interface WebApiService {

    @GET("users/login")
    suspend fun checkLogin(@Query("username") username: String,
                   @Query("password")password: String) : Users
```

How can I resolve issue of blocking my activity when waiting for retrieve data from server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should almost* never use `runBlocking` in an Android app. It is only meant to be used in the `main` function of a JVM app or in a test to allow the use of coroutines that complete before the app exits. It otherwise defeats the purpose of coroutines, because it blocks until all of its lambda returns.

You also shouldn't use GlobalScope, because it makes it tricky to cancel your jobs when the Activity closes, and it starts the coroutine in a background thread instead of the main thread. You should use a local scope for the Activity. You can do this by creating a property in your activity (`val scope = MainScope()`) and canceling it in `onDestroy()` (`scope.cancel()`). Or if you use the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx` library you can just use the existing `lifecycleScope` property.

And if you always `await` your async job before returning, then your whole function will block until you get the result, so you have taken a background task and made it block the main thread.

There are a couple ways you can go about fixing this.

1. Make the ViewModel expose a suspend function, and the activity calls it from a coroutine.

```
class LoginViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    //...

    // withContext(Dispatchers.Default) makes the suspend function do something
    // on a background thread and resumes the calling thread (usually the main 
    // thread) when the result is ready. This is the usual way to create a simple
    // suspend function. If you don't delegate to a different Dispatcher like this,
    // your suspend function runs its code in the same thread that called the function
    // which is not what you want for a background task.
    suspend fun getUser(username: String, password: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        userService.checkLogin(username, password)
    }
}

//In your activity somewhere:
lifecycleScope.launch {
    user = viewModel.getUser(login_username.text.toString(), login_password.text.toString())
    // do something with user
}
```

2. With proper viewmodel encapsulation, the Activity really shouldn't have to launch coroutines like this. The `user` property should be a LiveData in the ViewModel that the activity can observe. So then the coroutines only need to be launched from within the ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    //...
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user: LiveData<User> = _user

    init {
        fetchUser()
    }

    private fun fetchUser(username: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            userService.checkLogin(username, password)
        }
        _user.value = result
    }
}

//In your activity somewhere:
viewModel.user.observe(this) { user ->
    // do something with user
}
```

---

*If you are working with a library of code that doesn’t support coroutines and it requires you to override or implement a non-suspend function that will be called off the main thread and can handle blocking, long-running code, then it would be acceptable to use `runBlocking` as a bridge between these two worlds to be able to use you coroutine-based code when interacting with that library.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. I use second way, but both are true. I don't know anything about scopes and lifecycles. this problem showed to me I have to do more try about them. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know internet/wifi fetching or post needs to be in somekind of background/asynctask.
Have you tried using @Background/@Uithread from Android Annotations.
It will requiere you to put some dependencies in the gradle. 
But it's one way i have been dealing with services.

Here is the original link for the original DOC of it
https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads#background